# How to find out where in the network stack packets get filtered out

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2, ndis, wfp

Recently I found myself in [situations](https://serverfault.com/q/687107/124382) more than once where an app would not receive (multicast UDP) packets although they arrived at the NIC, and wireshark had captured the outgoing IGMP packets, confirming that the app is in fact joining the multicast groups.

But even while wireshark was capturing (i.e. promiscuous mode might have let packets through the NIC would have otherwise filtered out - for whatever reason), the app did not receive the packets. In other words, not the NIC, but the driver seems to be dropping the packets.

**How can I dig into this to figure out where the packets go astray?** Something to do with [WFP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366510.aspx) perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

If you suspect the packets have been dropped by WFP, then you should see them in `netsh trace` session output.

1. `netsh trace start scenario=wfp-ipsec`
2. ... repro your scenario ...
3. `netsh trace stop`

Look at the file named NetEvents.xml in the .cab file from the trace. The events listed as `FWPM_NET_EVENT_TYPE_CLASSIFY_DROP` are the result of WFP preventing the packet to propagate up (or down) the networking stack.

Comment: Thanks S.T. Will check it out next time I run into this. In the meantime, the [case](http://serverfault.com/q/687107/124382) I linked to in my question has - mysteriously - [resolved itself](http://serverfault.com/a/694644/124382).